# jpa hibernate, is it possible to list all rows of a table withouth specify a query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

The code I use to list all entries of a table is the following:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Cn=?", Entry.class).getResultList();
```

(I hope it is correct I still don't run the application).

As from title, is it possible to list entries without specifying a query ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use Criteria.

```
List<Person> persons = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Entry.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("Cn", "some value")).list();
```

However, there is other magic. Called [Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation). In Spring Data that would be

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

   List<Person> findByCn(String cn);

}
```